# A structure parameter is being skipped in my C program

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, newline, c-strings

So, this was my project:

You manage a travel agency and you want your n drivers to input their following details:

1. Name
2. Driving License No
3. Route
4. Kms
5. Your program should be able to take n as input(or you can take n=3 for simplicity) and your drivers will start inputting their details one by one.

Your program should print details of the drivers in a beautiful fashion.
User structures.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 struct driver_details
{
    char name[50];
    char licence_no[25];
    char route[20];
    char kms[5];
};

void displayDetails(struct driver_details arr)
{
    printf("\t1. Name of the driver: %s\n",arr.name);
    printf("\t2. Driving License Number: %s\n",arr.licence_no);
    printf("\t3. Route followed: %s\n",arr.route);
    printf("\t4. Total Kilometers travelled: %s\n",arr.kms);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of drivers:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct driver_details arr[n];
   
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the detail of driver number: %d\n",(i+1));

        printf("Enter your name:\n");
        gets(arr[i].name);

        printf("Enter your driving license number:\n");
        gets(arr[i].licence_no);

        printf("Enter your route:\n");
        gets(arr[i].route);

        printf("Enter the kilometers travelled:\n");
        gets(arr[i].kms);

        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("The details of the driver %s:\n",arr[i].name);
        displayDetails(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to take the user details one by one and then print them accordingly. But, when I ran my program, this was observed:

```
Enter the number of drivers:
1
Enter the detail of driver number: 1
Enter your name:
Enter your driving license number:
User
Enter your route:
xyz-abd
Enter the kilometers travelled:
2345

The details of the driver :
        1. Name of the driver:
        2. Driving License Number: User
        3. Route followed: xyz-abd
        4. Total Kilometers travelled: 2345
```

As shown, it totally skips the name attribute and I have tried various methods but they didn't work.
What should I do?

P.S : I am not that well-versed in structures

Comment: When asking a question here please remove anything not *strictly* necessary to illustrate the problem from your code. Here there's a ton of stuff relating to fields that aren't impacted by your problem.

Comment: You should never ever use `gets`. It is considered dangerous and was deprecated and even removed from standard decades ago. Use `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Do not use it. Instead use standard function `fgtes` or `scanf`.

The problem with your code is that after this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

As a result the next call of `gets` reads an empty string.

You should remove the new line character from the input buffer.

If to use `scanf` instead of `gets` then you can write for example like

```
scanf("%d",&n);
struct driver_details arr[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter the detail of driver number: %d\n",(i+1));

    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    scanf( " %49[^\n]", arr[i].name);
    //...
```

and so on using similar calls of `scanf`.

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters in the input buffer.

If to use `fgets` then you can write

```
scanf("%d",&n);
struct driver_details arr[n];

while ( getchar() != '\n' );

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter the detail of driver number: %d\n",(i+1));

    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    fgets( arr[i].name, sizeof( arr[i].name ), stdin );
    arr[i].name[ strcspn( arr[i].name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    //...
```

and use similar calls of `fgtes`.

To use the standard string function `strcspn` you need to include header `<string.h>`

Comment: I used scanf but it would just get ignored all at once:                              `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the detail of driver number: %d\n",(i+1));

        printf("Enter your name:\n");
        scanf("%49[^\n]",arr[i].name);

        printf("Enter your driving license number:\n");
        scanf("%24[^\n]",arr[i].licence_no);

        printf("Enter your route:\n");
        scanf("%19[^\n]",arr[i].route);

        printf("Enter the kilometers travelled:\n");
        scanf("%4[^\n]",arr[i].kms);

        printf("\n");
    }`

Comment: @SnigdhaPandey Reread my answer one more if one time to read it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `scanf` does not strip off the trailing newline unless asked, so your name input gets what seems to be a blank line.